# Can edit file as root, but not using sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

I just faced a really strange situation.

I was trying to edit file `/usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh`, which has the following permissions:

```
$ ll /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2730 Aug 20 12:55 /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh*
```

and I found that if I issue

```
sudo vim /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh
```

When I switch to insert mode I get a warning message:

```
/usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh [RO]
W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
-- INSERT --
```

And I actually cannot write any changes.

However, if I issue:

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo su -
root@hostname:~# vim /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh
```

I can edit the file without problems.

The strange thing is that I have edited lots of files with similar permissions, such as the configuration files in `/etc/`, without issues, and that If I create a file inside the same directory I have no problems editing it:

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo touch /usr/lib/thunderbird/test.sh
user@hostname:~$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/thunderbird/test.sh
user@hostname:~$ ll /usr/lib/thunderbird/test.sh /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Aug 20 13:03 /usr/lib/thunderbird/test.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2730 Aug 20 12:55 /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh*
user@hostname:~$ sudo vim /usr/lib/thunderbird/test.sh
```

This is my sudoers file:

```
# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias  APT = /usr/bin/apt-get update, /usr/bin/apt-get upgrade

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL 

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL 

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL 
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: APT
```

And my user is inside sudo group.

Any idea about why this happens?

Comment: When you're in `vim` editing the problematic file, what do you get when you enter this command: `:!echo "$UID:$EUID"`?

Comment: @JosephR.: Just "0:0". 
Also, :!id returns: "uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)". Funny...isn't it?

Comment: Strange indeed. Your `ls` output seems to indicate there are no ACLs either. The only thing I can think about is SELinux. Do you happen to have it enabled?

Comment: Does a different editor such as `nano` exhibit the same behavior? Also what if you `sudoedit` the file?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I just found the solution to the mistery.
Regarding `nano`, I cannot try because I removed it, but from what I have concluded, I would have had no problem with it.

Answer (score 8):

I just discovered the reason, and it was a collection of circumstances:

First of all, I don't know exactly why, but `sudo` was not grabbing the `HOME` environment variable properly and used the one of the regular user, so it read the `.vimrc` from `/home/user/.vimrc.`

In order to see this, I issued:

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for user: 
root@hostname:/home/user# echo $HOME
/home/user
```

Second, I have folding persistence enabled in my user's vimrc file in order to store cursor position:

```
au BufWinLeave * mkview
au BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```

This makes that every time a file is edited, a properties file is created inside `$HOME/.vim/view` folder.
In my case, it looks like I tried to edit the file without `sudo` the first time, so the folding file was created as regular user's:

```
user@hostname:~$ ll .vim/view/ | grep thunderbird.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  2650 Aug 20 15:56 =+usr=+lib=+thunderbird=+thunderbird.sh=
```

Since the root took `/home/user` as `$HOME`, the same folding file was (wrongly) used when I issued `sudo vim`, and for some reason that I ignore, probable related to vim internals, if the folding file is not owned by the editing user, the edited file is opened in ReadOnly mode.

So, I realized that if I removed the file `/home/user/.vim/view/=+usr=+lib=+thunderbird=+thunderbird.sh=` and then tried to edit using `sudo vim,` I had no problems at all.

So, at the end of the story, in order to fix this situation I just edited `/etc/sudoers` and added this line:

```
Defaults always_set_home
```

Now everything works as expected and I can use `sudo` reliably again.

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem with this command:

```
sudo chattr -i filename
```